# Permutations: selecting reviewers without conflicts of interest

Tags: matrix, permutation

I would like to automate the process of selecting a number of proposal reviewers that fit a conflict of interest criterion.  Let's say I have 5 reviewers and 5 applicants from 5 departments.  The department of a person can be obtained from the function `getdept`:

```
depts = { "science",  "language",  "art", "history",  "education"};
reviewers = { "mary", "jane", "bob", "joe", "john"};
applicants = { "mary", "pete",  "al", "fred", "patty"};
getdept[person_] := 
 person /. {"mary" -> "science", "jane" -> "language", 
   "bob" -> "art", "joe" -> "history", "john" -> "education", 
   "pete" -> "language", "al" -> "art", "fred" -> "art", 
   "patty" -> "language"}
```

Each proposal must be read by three reviewers, none of whom can be from the same department as the applicant.  I can generate a table of possible reviewers:

```
possrev = 
 Table[{i, 
   DeleteCases[reviewers, x_ /; getdept[x] === getdept[i]]}, {i, 
   applicants}]
```

And looking at the result in this trivial example, I can manually identify reviewers:

```
possrev[[All, 2]] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I'm stuck with how to select sublists.  It looks to me as if I should end with a 3xN matrix where N is the number of applicants.  No element in the resulting matrix would be represented more than three times.  (We can assume that `Length[reviewers] >= Length[applicants]`).  I suspect that there will not be unique solutions and I do not need all solutions (although that would be interesting).

Is it possible to find a solution matrix, `assignments` such that:

```
Length/@Union/@assignments = 3
```

and

```
Count[Flatten[assignments], #] & /@ reviewers <= 3
```

[I think these are the correct mathematical representations of my criteria, but I may be mistaken.]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit**

I like the following formulation much more than the previous one. Using lists without indexing is clearer for me:

```
b[i_, j_] := Boole[getdept[applicants[[i]]] != getdept[reviewers[[j]]]]
lr = Length@reviewers;
la = Length@applicants;
sc = SparseArray[{i_, j_} -> c[i, j], {la, lr}];
sconds = SparseArray[{i_, j_} :> (0 <= c[i, j] <= b[i, j]), {la, lr}];
sol = Solve[{
             And @@ Thread[Tr /@ sc == 3] &&            (*3 reviewrs per applicant*)
             And @@ Thread[Tr /@ Transpose[sc] <= 3] && (*at most 3 tasks per reviewer*)
             And @@ Flatten@sconds},                    (*conflict test*)
       Normal@Flatten@sc, Integers];
MatrixForm /@ (Normal /@ sc /. sol)
```

**Previous incarnation**

Perhaps:

```
b[i_, j_] := 1 /; (getdept[applicants[[i]]] != getdept[reviewers[[j]]])
b[i_, j_] := 0 /; (getdept[applicants[[i]]] == getdept[reviewers[[j]]])
lr = Length@reviewers;
la = Length@applicants;
t = Table[c[i, j], {i, la}, {j, lr}];
sol = Solve[{And @@ Table[ Sum[c[i, j], {j, lr}] == 3, {i, la}] && (*3 reviewrs per applicant*)
             And @@ Table[ Sum[c[i, j], {i, la}] <= 3, {j, lr}] && (*at most 3 tasks per reviewer*)
             And @@ Flatten@ Table[0 <= c[i, j] <= b[i, j], {i, la}, {j, lr}]}, (*conflict test*)
            Flatten@t, Integers];
MatrixForm /@ (t /. # & /@ sol)
```

So, the first solution is:

```
f = {#1 , "is reviewed by", #2} &;
Thread[f[applicants, ((t /. sol[[1]]).reviewers)]]

(*
 {{mary, is reviewed by, bob  + jane + john},
  {pete, is reviewed by, bob  + joe  + john},
  {al,   is reviewed by, jane + john + mary},
  {fred, is reviewed by, jane + joe  + mary},
  {patty,is reviewed by, bob  + joe  + mary}}
*)
```

And there are 24 of such solutions (`Length@sol`)

Comment: Very nice - If you could also include the `RemoveInternalStrife[]` condition that will allow me to step aside and have Mathematica run this committee.

Comment: @bobthechemist I resist doing such things. Mathematica could start claiming its worker rights.

Comment: The only danger of letting Mathematica run everything is that everyone will be renamed Wolfram...

Comment: Hmm, does the OP not get pinged when an answer gets edited?  I missed your update.

Comment: @bobthechemist I think you should get a ping, but not completely sure about that. Ask a mod.

Answer (score 3):

I think @belisarius code deals with general cases without the nice symmetries/regularity of the toy example. However, I post for interest(?):

This question is related to bipartite matching. In the following I have modified "mary" who can be a reviewer or applicant to "maryrev" and "maryapp".

Setting up (then):

depts = {"science", "language", "art", "history", "education"};

```
reviewers = {"maryrev", "jane", "bob", "joe", "john"};
applicants = {"maryapp", "pete", "al", "fred", "patty"};
getdept[person_] := 
 person /. {"maryapp" -> "science", "maryrev" -> "science", 
   "jane" -> "language", "bob" -> "art", "joe" -> "history", 
   "john" -> "education", "pete" -> "language", "al" -> "art", 
   "fred" -> "art", "patty" -> "language"}
```

The bipartite graph can be generated (and faciltate 'by hand solution'):

```
gr = Select[Flatten[Outer[Rule, reviewers, applicants]], 
  Not[getdept[#[[1]]] == getdept[#[[2]]]] &]
g = Graph[gr, VertexLabels -> "Name", VertexLabelStyle -> 20, 
  ImagePadding -> 60]
```

[image]

Aiming to find solutions:

```
candid = {EdgeList[g, _ \[DirectedEdge] #][[All, 1]], #} & /@ 
  applicants;
ca = candid[[All, 1]];
sub = Subsets[#, {3}] & /@ ca;
ot = List @@@ Flatten[Outer[cand, ##, 1] & @@ sub];
answer = Select[ot, Max[Tally[Join @@ #][[All, 2]]] <= 3 &];
```

Reassuringly,

```
Length[answer]
```

yields 24 (as per belisarius...not a guarantee they are same and if not I am likely wrong)

An example:

```
Thread[answer[[1]] -> candid[[All, 2]]]
```

yields:

```
{{"jane", "bob", "joe"} -> "maryapp", {"maryrev", "bob", "joe"} -> 
  "pete", {"maryrev", "jane", "john"} -> 
  "al", {"maryrev", "jane", "john"} -> 
  "fred", {"bob", "joe", "john"} -> "patty"}
```

Confirmation compliance with 'at most 3':

```
Tally[Join @@ answer[[1]]]
```

gives:

```
{{"jane", 3}, {"bob", 3}, {"joe", 3}, {"maryrev", 3}, {"john", 3}}
```

...significant thought and modification (for me) would be needed for irregular case with varying vertex out/in degrees...hence my support for belisarius answer

**EDIT**

confirmation of 'conflict' test:

```
test = Thread[{#, candid[[All, 2]]}] & /@ answer;
tf[u_] := Or @@ Thread[getdept /@ u[[1]] == getdept[u[[2]]]];
Or @@ Flatten[Map[tf, test, {2}]]
```

`tf` tests whether any reviewer is in same faculty. The final line tests all answers and yields False, i.e. in no solution is an applicant interviewed by a reviewer from same faculty.